# Iterating over integer strings with bounded entries and fixed sum

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

Let $S = \{ 0, 1, \dots d\}^n$ be the set of strings (ordered tuples) with integer entries between $0$ and $d$. Consider the subset of strings $A \subset S$ whose entries sum to $k \cdot d$. Notationally, we can write this as $A = \{ s_1 s_2 \dots s_n \mid \sum_{i=1}^n s_i = k \cdot d, \text{ and }s_i \in \{0, \dots d\} \text{ for all } \ i=1,\dots n \}$.

I am looking for an algorithm that iterates over the strings in $A$. One might try to iterate over the strings in lexicographical order, starting with 
$\underbrace{d \ d \dots d}_{k \text{ times }} \ 
\underbrace{0 \ 0 \dots 0}_{n-k \text{ times }}$
and ending with 
$\underbrace{0 \ 0 \dots 0}_{n-k \text{ times }} \ 
\underbrace{d \ d \dots d}_{k \text{ times }}$.

For small values of $n$, $d$, and $k$, I have written down the iteration over $A$ in lexicographical order but I haven't been able to explicitly come up with an algorithm.

Comment: Why not simplest backtrack algorithm?

Comment: thanks for the comment, @Vladislav. Can you describe more precisely what you mean? Perhaps in the form of an answer is best too.

Comment: For $d=1$ there's [Gosper's hack](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/67087/13258).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $L(n,d,t)$ be the lexicographically sorted list of strings of length $n$ with entries between $0$ and $d$ whose sum is $t$. You want $L(n,d,nk)$. This list can be computed recursively via
$$
\begin{align}
L(n,d,t)=
&\quad((d)+\ell\mid \ell\in L(n-1,d,t-d))
\\&+((d-1)+\ell\mid \ell\in L(n-1,d,t-(d-1))
\\&+\vdots
\\&+((1)+\ell\mid \ell\in L(n-1,d,t-1))
\\&+((0)+\ell\mid \ell\in L(n-1,d,t-0))
\end{align}
$$
In other words, you recursively compute $L(n-1,d,t-d)$, then prepend the symbol $d$ to each list in that list. Then compute $L(n-1,d,t-(d-1))$, prepend the symbol $d$ to each list in that list, and concatenate the result to the previous list. And so on.

In pseudo-code:

```
def all_strings(n,d,t):
  if t = 0:
    yield the string of n zeroes, then stop iterating
  if t < 0 or n = 0:
    stop iterating
  for k in {d,d-1,...,1,0}:
    iterate though all_strings(n-1,d,t-k), prepending each with k
```

**Edit:** Even simpler. Given a string, $s$ here is how you find the next string in lexicographical order.

Every string $s$ can be uniquely written in the form $$s=t\mid x\mid 0^i\mid y\mid d^{j},$$ where $\mid$ is concatenation, $i,j\ge 0$,$x,y\in \{0,1,2\dots,d\}$, with $y\neq d$ and $x\neq 0$, and $t$ is a string. In words, $j$ is the number of $d$'s at the end of $s$, $y$ is the letter just before the $d$'s, $i$ the length of the block of zeroes just before $y$, and $x$ is the number before those zeroes, while $t$ is everything else.

Then the successor of $s$ is
$$
s'=t\mid(x-1)\mid d^j\mid(y+1)\mid 0^i.
$$

Comment: Nice observation that you can iterate over the set of strings $A$ recursively! Do you know of a way to change the recursive iterator into a non-recursive one by somehow unrolling the recursion?

Comment: @ChrisHarshaw Yes. Maintain a stack of partial strings. Over and over, pop a string s from the stack, and push on s with all possible characters appended to s. When the sum of s is equal to kd, then yield s padded with zeroes (or whatever the non python equivalent of yield is).

Comment: @ChrisHarshaw Actually see edit for an even simpler method, which works similarly to Gosper's hack.